# Perc 4 Configuration - Drives not showing up

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, scsi, dell-perc

Hello I am trying to configure raid on a PERC 4 running in a PowerEdge 1850.  When I go into the bios configuration for the raid controller the drives I have attached are not present.  Specifically when I go to the easy configuration screen all I see is "Processor" and no drives.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  These drives are Ultra 320 SCSI.  Is there a jumper or something else that I need to set on the drives perhaps?

Comment: I went through some more settings in the configuration utility - the drives do not show up as logical or physical disks.

Comment: Are the drives Dell-branded or flashed with Dell firmware?

Comment: do the drives flash any lights when you plug them in? do ANY drives work in this chassis at all?

Comment: Hi dyasny, check out my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather embarrassing but it's also comical so I'll post it anyway.  I could entertain you with saying I had to upgrade the firmware or something.  In my haste and excitement I forgot to load the drives into the box :)  I was not working facing the front so this was not obvious for a few minutes.  Since I was using used parts fear led me to the dark-side, fearing that I had bought bad or out-dated parts.  But  yes your RAID array will show zero physical disks .. if you don't physically load them. Thankfully it didn't take me too long to realize this :)

Comment: Upvote for that one. ;-)
Reminds me of an old joke: Support: What is on your monitor?
Customer: A vase...
Can you delete your question?